# How to use transaction using object persistence model against DynamoDB?

Tags: transactions, amazon-dynamodb

We were using Object Persistence Model(.net core version) to operate against DynamoDB and everything is good so far, now I am going to survey is there any possible to use transaction in Object Persistence Model but I did not seem to find a corresponding API after looking over the official API documentation. Can anybody have the same issue and the corresponding solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: or even how to do it in low level API, I am not able to find any documents or code example on it.

Comment: I was able to figure it out using low level API with C# yesterday, but it was such a pain, there is not much document or code sample for dynamoDB transaction using .net core.

Comment: Can you share the sample using low level apis?